# MeteorJS: CALLBACKS

Tags: meteor, callback

**PROBLEM:** I want to parse the elements in a page from another website, glue resulting elements in an object and insert it in a Mongo collection. Before insertion i want to check if my Mongo yet has an identical object. If it does it shall exit the running functions, otherwise i want the script to start parsing the next target.

**Example:**

1. I have a function that connects to a webpage and returns its `body` content
2. It is parsed
3. When `<a></a>` elements are met, another callback is called in which all parsed elements are merged in one object and inserted in a collection

My code :

```
var Cheerio  = Meteor.npmRequire('cheerio');
var lastUrl;
var exit = false;
Meteor.methods({
  parsing:function(){
    this.unblock();
    request("https://example.com/", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        $ = Cheerio.load(body);
        var k = 1;
        $("div.content").each(function() {
          var name = $...//parsing
          var age = $....//parsing
          var url = $...//parsing <a></a> elements
          var r = request("https://example.com/"+url, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(error, response, body) {
            lastUrl = response.request.uri.href;// get the last routing link
            var metadata = {
              name: name,
              age: age
              url: lastUrl
            };
            var postExist;
            postExist = Posts.findOne(metadata); // return undefined if doesnt exist, AND every time postExist = undefined ??
            if (!postExist){
              Posts.insert(metadata);// if post doesnt exist (every time go here ??)
            }
            else {
              exit = true; // if exist
            }
          }));
          if (exit === true) return false;
        });
      }
  }));
}
});
```

**Problem 1 :** The problem is my function works every time, but it doesn't stop even if the object exists in my collection

**Problem 2 :** postExist is always undefined

**EDIT :** The execution must stop and wait until the second request's response.

```
var url = $...//parsing <a></a> elements 

//STOP HERE AND WAIT !!

var r = request("https://example.com/"+url, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(error, response, body) {
```

Comment: _UNTIL my database doesn't exist same document IF object exist I must exit all functions._ This is an unknown language on earth

Comment: @Atrahasis edited, i hope it more non _unknown language on earth_  haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want the second request to be synchronous and not asynchronous.

To achieve this, use a future

```
var Cheerio  = Meteor.npmRequire('cheerio');
var Future = Meteor.npmRequire('fibers/future');
var lastUrl;
var exit = false;
Meteor.methods({
  parsing:function(){
    this.unblock();
    request("https://example.com/", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        $ = Cheerio.load(body);
        var k = 1;
        $("div.content").each(function() {
          var name = $...//parsing
          var age = $....//parsing
          var url = $...//parsing <a></a> elements
          var fut = new Future();
          var r = request("https://example.com/"+url, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(error, response, body) {
            lastUrl = response.request.uri.href;// get the last routing link
            var metadata = {
              name: name,
              age: age
              url: lastUrl
            };
            var postExist;
            postExist = Posts.findOne(metadata); // return undefined if doesnt exist
            if (!postExist) {
              Posts.insert(metadata);// if post doesnt exist (every time go here ??)
              fut.return(true);
            } else {
              fut.return(false);
            }
          }));
          var status = fut.wait();
          return status;
        });
      }
    }));
  }
});
```

You can use futures whenever you can't utilize callback functions (e.g. you want the user to wait on the result of a callback before presenting info).

Hopefully that helps,

Elliott

Answer (score 0):

This is the opposite :

```
postExist = Posts.findOne(metadata); // return undefined if doesnt exist > you're right
if (!postExist){ //=if NOT undefined = if it EXISTS !
    Posts.insert(metadata);
}else {
    exit = true; // if undefined > if it DOES NOT EXIST !
}
```

You need to inverse the condition or the code inside

Comment: This doesn't solved main problem such as _exit all functions if my Mongo has "equal" object_